# How to make language parameter optional with $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-translate

I am using $stateProvider for routing and angular-translate for translations. What i would like to achieve is having the selected language bind to the URL and make Language optional with [default=en].
like so:

```
www.mydomain.com/home
www.mydomain.com/en/home
www.mydomain.com/ar/home
```

and make it  respond accordingly.

I used this code

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
$stateProvider
        // Homepage:
        .state("app", {
            url: "/:lang?",
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        })


        .state("app.home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "common/views/main.html"
        });
```

i want to go to home page with language parameter like

```
www.mydomain.com/en/home
```

or without it like

```
www.mydomain.com/home
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the url

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
$stateProvider
    // Homepage:
    .state("app", {
        url: "/:lang",
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "common/views/main.html"
    });
```

in your controller

```
$state.go("app",{lang:"en"});
```

Attention: the name of the url variable should be the same as put in the $ state

Comment: can i navigate to
www.mydomain.com/home
www.mydomain.com/en/home

Comment: can i navigate to

[ www.mydomain.com/home ]
[www.mydomain.com/en/home]

Comment: i need to navigate without language

Comment: then create a demo that replicates problem. Not really clear what it is from the description

Comment: i want to go to home page with language parameter or without it .

Comment: It seems you that you want your url to be www.mydomain.com/home not www.mydomain.com/en/home (with en), correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `squash: true` option for optional parameters in the `params` property of the configuration. When the parameter value is the default one, this will remove any slashes around it too.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
$stateProvider
    // Homepage:
    .state("app", {
        url: "/:lang",
        params: {squash: true, value: 'en'}
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })


    .state("app.home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "common/views/main.html"
    });
```

Note that this will not include the default value in generated routes, so even though `/en/home` works, a link with `ui-sref='app.home({lang:"en"})'` will yield `/home`, not `/en/home`. You can set up `value: null` and use the `"en"` as default in your language selection logic later when $stateParams.lang is null.

Comment: I came across a solution for this and updated the answer, this should work for your case too.